# Watchguard logs incoming SMTP connections has an dst_user entry. Where can I change this entry?

Tags: exchange, logging, watchguard

Hello fellow Exchangers,
as mentioned in the title any incoming smtp connection is routed correctly to our onpremise microsoft exchange server and the logs look as described here:
https://www.watchguard.com/help/docs/help-center/en-US/Content/en-US/Fireware/logging/read_log-msg.html
But just the incoming smtp connections has an additional entry "dst_user" and it is the same coworker@our-domain for all recipients x,y,z@our-domain.

On the watchguard manual I was able to read:
At the end of each log message for traffic from an authenticated user, you can see the user name associated with the IP addresses, for example src_user="TestUser@Firebox-DB". When you review a log message, the source user appears as the value for the src_user detail and the destination user appears as the value for the dst_user detail.

so I only can imagine the ip of our microsoft exchange server is associated to this specific user in our domain... but it is not our Administrator... so I cannot imagine the user had this static ip outside of the dhcp area associated to him or that he is the owner of the exchange server...

Any thoughts? :l